# Issue with Makefile in top level directory, sources in subdirectories

Tags: makefile, subdirectory

I have a directory called `project`.

It contains two sub-directories called `client` and `server`, and a makefile called `Makefile`.

`client` and `server` have got source files called `client.c` and `server.c`, respectively.

I don't have any separate makefiles in the subdirectories for sources belonging to that directory. All builds are done by the single makefile. The `Makefile` code is

```
FLAGS = -W -Wall -g -pthread

SERV =./server/server.c      #My server code 
CLI =./client/client.c       #My client code

build:svr cnt

svr: $(SERV) 
    cc $(FLAGS) $(SERV) -o ./server/server.out
cnt: $(CLI)
    cc $(FLAGS) $(CLI) -o ./client/client.out
```

Now I ran `make cnt` and it replied

```
cc -W -Wall -g -pthread ./client/client.c -o ./client/client.out
```

The problem is all the subsequent `make cnt` commands end up compiling it again and outputting the above text even though I'm not changing `./client/client.c`

I'm stuck here. Don't know what to do.

What I want to do is:

- With `make cnt`, compile `client/client.c` and output its executable in the `client/` directory
- With `make svr`, compile `server/server.c` and output its executable in `server/` directory.
- And with `make, compile both`server/server.c`and`client/client.c` and output their executables in their respective directories

But since I don't have any executables called `svr` and `cnt the problem I am having isn't solved.

If I change the target to `./client/client.out` instead of `cnt` and then call `make client/client.out` then it would be fine, exactly what I need but I don't want to enter long command `make client/client.out` in my terminal

The workaround I have got is as follows

```
cnt: $(CLI)
         cc $(FLAGS) $(CLI) -o cnt
         cp cnt ./client/client.out
```

But not quite satisfied with it. I'm sure what I want to do is really simple and there should be some convenient way around doing it. So how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's formulate what you want.  You want target named `cnt' not to be rebuilt.  The makefile you've written knows nothing about client.out file, because it only appears in shell commands within a rule.  Make program doesn't read information from shell commands, it only does substitutions there and executes them.

When makefile chooses the targets it will rebuild (`cnt' is one of these targets), it compares update time of a target **file** with update time of its prerequsites.  Since at the time you run ``make  cnt'' **the file named cnt is absent**, the target named so is considered as requiring update.  So commands are run and yield no **file named cnt**, so next make run will consider it for updating as well.

There are two possible solutions.  The first one is to give targets same names as of the file, that the rule commands will generate.  So, you might end up like this:

```
client/client.out: $(CLI)
    cc $(FLAGS) $(CLI) -o ./client/client.out
```

Your questioin has nothing to do with directories, by the way.  You should also read about .PHONY directive, use $(CC) instead of cc and read [gnu make manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/), which  might be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SERVO =./server/server.out
CLIO =./client/client.out

.PHONY: srv cnt build
build: svr cnt
svr: $(SERVO)
cnt: $(CLIO)

$(SERVO) $(CLIO): %.out : %.c
    cc $(FLAGS) $^ -o $@
```

Now you can **make srv**, **make cnt**, or just **make**.

There are slightly more sophisticated things you can do, but this should be enough for now.

Comment: I am not able to follow it. I dont have much experience in making makefiles so I guess I will read the manual sometime later. Right now I will go ahead with copying cnt to my client directory.Thanks

Comment: All right, but you'll remake client.out every time, whether you really need to or not.